# Update a field in a JSON column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, database, postgresql, jsonb

I have a *work_item* table that has the following schema

```
+---------+----------+---------------+
|  id     |   data   |   data_type   |
+------------------------------------+
|         |          |               |
|         |          |               |
|         |          |               |
+---------+--------------------------+
```

and a *document_type* table with the following schema:

```
+---------+----------+
|  id     | name     |
+--------------------+
|         |          |
|         |          |
|         |          |
+---------+-----------
```

The data column is a **json** column that has a **Type** field. This is a sample column data:

```
{"Id":"5d35a41f-3e91-4eda-819d-0f2d7c2ba55e","WorkItem":"24efa9ea-4291-4b0a-9623-e6122201fe4a","Type":"Tax Document","Date":"4/16/2009"}
```

I need to update data columns whose `data_type` column value is **DocumentModel**  and **Type** field values matches a value in the name column of the *document_type* table to a json object containing the document_type id and the document_type name. Something like this `{"id": "<doc_type_id>", name: "<doc_type_name>"}`.

I tried to do this by executing this query:

```sql
UPDATE wf.work_item wi
SET data = jsonb_set(data::jsonb, '{Type}', (
    SELECT jsonb_build_object('id', dt.id, 'name', dt.name) 
      FROM wf.document_type AS dt 
     WHERE wi.data ->> 'Type'::text = dt.name::text
), false)
WHERE wi.data_type = 'DocumentModel';
```

The above script runs without an error. However, what it does is something unwanted, it changes the *data* and *data_type* columns to *null* instead of updating the *data* column.

What is the issue with my script? Or can you suggest a better alternative to do a the desired update?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem arises when the document type is missing from the `document_type` table. Then `jsonb_set()` returns `null` (as the subquery does not give any results). A safer solution is to use the `from` clause in `update`:

```
update wf.work_item wi
set data = jsonb_set(
    data::jsonb, 
    '{Type}',
    jsonb_build_object('id', dt.id, 'name', dt.name),
    false)
from wf.document_type as dt 
where wi.data_type = 'DocumentModel'
and wi.data ->> 'Type'::text = dt.name::text;
```